# How to pip install a Fork Repo

Tags: git, github, pip

I have recently forked repo and then made some changes but when I was trying to pip install that.

I get this following error

Tried:

```
pip install https://github.com/RahulARanger/py-googletrans.git#egg=pytubex
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Cannot unpack file C:\Users\[Name]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-uyk9f4ze\pytubeX.git (downloaded from C:\Users\[Name]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-826d06sl\pytubex, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\[Name]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-826d06sl\pytubex
```

Tried:

```
pip install git+git//github.com/RahulARanger/py-googletrans.git@master
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\[name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\[name]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-fksh4wb0\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\[name]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-fksh4wb0\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-lolv29nn'
         cwd: C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-fksh4wb0\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-fksh4wb0\setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        README = (here / "README.md").read_text()
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Fork Repo: https://github.com/RahulARanger/py-googletrans

Yes, I have uninstalled the main ones (pytubex)

Do I need to make some changes in Fork or change my command?
I have tried most of the prev suggestions in some questions before but it didn't work
Please help me with this issue.